# Creating a list of UUIDs for a test in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mocking

I want to generate a mock `List<UUID>` and fill it using random UUID's. However, I am not sure if there is a more proper way instead of the following approach by creating list and adding items.

```
List<UUID> uuidList = new ArrayList<>();
uuidList.add(UUID.randomUUID());
uuidList.add(UUID.randomUUID());
uuidList.add(UUID.randomUUID());
```

So, is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Java8 streams here.

```
List<UUID> uuidList = Stream.generate(UUID::randomUUID)
        .limit(3)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will generate 3 random UUIDs, for more, just change the `limit`.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 9:

```
import static java.util.UUID.randomUUID;
List<UUID> uuidList = List.of(randomUUID(), randomUUID(), randomUUID());
```

Comment: Thanks for helps. But assume that I generate 10 random items. Is there a better way?

Comment: Indeed, the accepted answer is a better choice in this case.

Comment: Ok, I market it as answer. Anyway, thanks a lot for your helps.